# Fos User Bundle for Symfony 3.2 does not support propel datastore anymore?

Tags: fosuserbundle, propel2, symfony-3.2

I've been running *Symfony 2.3* and used *FOS User Bundle* a lot so I reused some of my *config.yml* configuration in a new project with *Symfony 3.2.8*. I just restored FOS User Bundle via composer and I am wondering why that vendor package is lacking the user class `FOS\UserBundle\Propel\UserManager` which was used in the older version. Also, I cannot specify 'propel' as the 'user_class' in *config.yml*. 
I get the message:

> 'The driver "propel" is not supported. Please choose one of ["orm","mongodb","couchdb","custom"].

What should be done? Implement the Propel User Manager as a custom user class?

Thanks a lot for the info!
Regards,
Steffen

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it by setting driver to `"orm"` and using `FOS\UserBundle\Propel\User`.

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    user_class: FOS\UserBundle\Propel\User
```